# Creating an iterator to act like an observable/go channel, why does it only emit ungrouped async events?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am modelling a reactivity handler from rxjs and Golang channels. I am trying to use iterators to achieve this however my "Channel" only emits when an async event is supplied. Why is that?

Here is my consumer code

```
import { Channel } from "./channel";

const numbers: any = new Channel();

void async function() {
  for (const number of numbers) {
    // Will pause and wait for emit()
    console.log(await number);
  }
}();

numbers.emit(1);
numbers.emit(2);
numbers.emit(3);
setTimeout(() => numbers.emit(4));
setTimeout(() => numbers.emit(5), 50);
setTimeout(() => numbers.emit(6), 100);
```

This is my "Channel" implementation.

```
export class Channel<T = any> {
  private onValue = new PromiseSubject()

  emit(value: T): void {
    this.onValue.resolve(value)
    this.onValue = new PromiseSubject()
  }

  *[Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<Promise<T>> {
    while (true) {
      yield this.onValue.promise
    }
  }    
}

export class PromiseSubject<T = any> {
  public resolve!: (value?: T) => void
  public promise = new Promise<T>((res) => this.resolve = res)
}
```

I expect an output of `123456` however I only get `456`. It seems when events are bunched together the iterator doesn't yield a value.

Similarly, I get no console output when I run:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  numbers.emit(1)
  numbers.emit(2)
  numbers.emit(3)
})
```

Sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-wave-y0o3e?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to implement somekind of queue.
With

```
 this.onValue = new PromiseSubject()
```

you override the current `onValue`, when you call the iterator (with `for of`) you only await the current `onValue`, not the promises stored there before.

There are however async iterators, that do exactly what you are looking for!

```
 export class Channel<T = any> {
   toEmit = [] as T[];
   resolveLast: Promise?;

  emit(value: T): void {
    if(this.resolveLast) this.resolveLast(value);
    else this.toEmit.push(value);
  }

  async *[Symbol.iterator](): {
    while (true) {
      const value = this.toEmit.shift();
      yield value;
      if(this.toEmit.length === 0)
         await new Promise(res => this.resolveLthis.resolveLast = res);
    }
  }    
}

 // iterable as
 for await(const el of new Channel)
```

Recommended reading:

[Jake Archibald on async iterators](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/async-iterators-and-generators/)